# How to get my dropdown to default to first row name in table

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, extjs

Edit: more code

```
Dim oControl As New Forms.Control()

                            Using types As New DataSet
                                With oDal
                                    .Parameters.Clear()
                                    .Execute(sql, types)
                                End With
                                With ddlType
                                    .DataSource = types.Tables(0)
                                    .DataTextField = "Name"
                                    .DataValueField = "TypeId"
                                    .Items.Clear()
                                    .DataBind()
                                    If .Items.Count > 0 Then
                                        .SelectedIndex = 0
                                    End If
                                End With

                            End Using
                            'set queue type with our asp:dropdownlist control
                            oControl = New Forms.Control(Forms.Control.ControlType.ComboBox)
                            'we need to connect the two controls
                            oControl.Id = ddlType.ID

                            'add it to the grid
                            With .Columns.Add("CredentialTypeId", "Type", 85)
                                .Editor = oControl
                            End With
```

For some reason when you click the dropdown - "0" is displayed defaulted. It needs to be the first text/value pair from the table. The table is only returning one row at the moment, which is correct, but 0 still defaults.

Anyone know why?

Comment: I'm confused how can it default to 0 if only one record is returned?  Is that record equal to 0?  Is there more code that we are not seeing?

Comment: The record is not equal to zero. I have no idea why this is happening. It's almost as if '0' is added to the dropdown as the first item and it's becoming the default. I tried setting the default manually to item(0), which didn't do anything, and item(1), which errored.

Comment: Yeah I usually have a method that adds a default value to the dropdown so I have something to test with to see if the user has selected anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
With ddlType
    .DataSource = types.Tables(0)
    .DataTextField = "Name"
    .DataValueField = "TypeId"
    .DataBind()
    If .Items.Count > 0 Then
      .SelectedIndex = 0
    End If
End With
```

**Edit**:
Given your results and your comments, I think either your *types* table is empty or your code isn't being run. Try adding some breakpoints and testing some values.

```
types.Tables(0) isnot nothing
types.Tables(0).Rows.Count
```

**Edit2**:
Looking at your code, I see a different problem. You never fill oControl. I am not sure why you are creating a completely new control and setting it's ID to ddlType's ID. Why don't you just do your databind with oControl? Or attach ddlType to your grid?

Comment: For some reason this isn't working. This is what I tried first. The ddl is within an ExtJS grid if that makes a difference. The DDL is actually a column.

Comment: The table does have data. the Dropdown becomes {0, firstElement}. I just want it to display firstElement instead of 0, and I have NO IDEA how the 0 is even getting there in the first place.

Comment: You were on the right track. My bad. I followed your thought process and eventually found that when the new row was inserted, a javascript method was running and for some reason CHANGING the typeId brought back from the database to the first one. Bad code =/

Answer (score 0):

I know this probably won't work but going to say it anyway.

Have you tried to clear all the items before binding the data?

```
ddType.Items.Clear();
```